# react-native-track-player notification view disabling or removal

Tags: react-native, react-native-track-player

```
await TrackPlayer.updateOptions({
 android: {
  appKilledPlaybackBehavior:
    AppKilledPlaybackBehavior.StopPlaybackAndRemoveNotification,
},
// This flag is now deprecated. Please use the above to define playback mode.
stoppingAppPausesPlayback: true,
capabilities: [
  Capability.Play,
  Capability.Pause,
  Capability.SkipToNext,
  Capability.SkipToPrevious,
  Capability.SeekTo,
],
compactCapabilities: [Capability.Play, Capability.Pause],
progressUpdateEventInterval: 1,
});
```

How to Disable the notification view on the react-native-track-player.Is there any option in the library for that ?

Here,"appKilledPlaybackBehavior:AppKilledPlaybackBehavior.StopPlaybackAndRemoveNotification" is provided but still, the notification is not removed

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue. Still there is a open issue on the library repository.
https://github.com/doublesymmetry/react-native-track-player/issues/2193

Try updating the react-native-track-player to v 4.0.1. They have added a fix. But didn't work for me.